# Get custom attribute value in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, attr

I have this **html**

```
<a data-overlay="Preparing First" href='#'>First link</a>
<a data-overlay="Preparing Second" href='#'>Second link</a>
```

And **JS**

```
$("[data-overlay]").click(function () {
        var text = $(this).val($(this).attr("data-overlay"));
        alert(text);
    });
```

When I do this, I got only OBJECT, where I got wrong?

Here is working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sruq8kav/

What I need is to alert value of that custom attribute?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because you're alerting the result of `.val()` (and I'm not sure why you're using it) which is a jQuery object - you simply want the attribute:

```
var text = $(this).attr("data-overlay")
alert(text);
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [tymeJV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26631232/3187556), you can also get `data-` attributes in jQuery with the `.data()` method.

```
var text = $(this).data("overlay")
alert(text);
```

Be aware that doing so will return numbers, Booleans, or objects, if jQuery detects the data to be of that type. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126017/html5-data-attribute-type-casting-strings-and-numbers/26126302#26126302).